# Configuring Brother QL-820NWBc Label Printer for Remote Access and Multi-Store Communication

Tags: label, project, remote-access, network-printers, brother-print-sdk

Hi Stack Overflow Community,

I'm working on a project that involves setting up multiple Brother QL-820NWBc label printers in different stores, and I need them to be accessible from a remote location. The goal is to enable my central server, located outside the stores, to send print jobs to each printer individually for processing orders efficiently.

The challenges I'm facing are:

Remote Access: I want to be able to print to the label printers from my central server, which is located at a different physical location (e.g., my school). The printers are connected to their respective store networks, and I want to find a secure way to send print jobs to them over the internet without the need to manually access each store's network.

Centralized Communication: To streamline order processing, I need to communicate with each printer individually. My central server should be able to send print jobs to each printer separately and receive confirmation of successful print completion.

I have done some research, and while I found options like VPN, cloud printing services, and VPN tunneling, they don't seem to be the solution because we will need to setup vpn connections with evey story that works with us which needs to be manually connected every time an order comes in for a store. But please correct me if I am wrong with this statement.

I looked into ISS (Internet Printing for Secure Servers) as well. However, I couldn't find a straightforward way to configure the Brother QL-820NWBc label printer to have a publicly accessible IP address for direct internet printing. Is it possible that it just doens't have a way to connect to a device outside of the LAN? It has ethernet and wifi access on the printer itself.

Here are some specific questions I have:

1. What is the most secure and efficient way to enable remote access to the Brother QL-820NWBc label printers from a central server?
2. Can I utilize the Brother QL-820NWBc's built-in features or firmware updates to achieve remote printing capabilities?
3. Is there a cloud printing service that supports Brother QL-820NWBc label printers and allows individual communication with each printer from my central server?
4. How can I ensure that the setup is secure and prevents unauthorized access to the printers or my central server?

If anyone has experience with setting up remote printing and multi-store communication with the Brother QL-820NWBc label printers, and if you have insights into configuring remote access or any alternatives to ISS, I would greatly appreciate your guidance and recommendations. Any code examples or specific steps to achieve this would be immensely helpful.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!